# magento 2 product page price microdata not matching google xml feed

Tags: xml, seo, feed, magento2, microdata

I cannot find an answer to this anywhere!

I have a magento2 site that is generating microdata as per the default installation, albeit not strictly formatted to my mind, but is the default output for magento 2 product listings.
We also have related products on these pages further down in the code.

See below code excerpt:

```
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span  id="product-price-6" data-price-amount="1169.496001" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper " itemprop="price">
    <span class="price" content="1169.50">£1,169.50</span>    </span>
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
```

We then submit a site map xml feed to google, but google double checks our page and picks up the related products at the bottom of the html randomly and assigns them as the price instead of the main product price.

Related products price code excerpt:

```
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
    <span  id="product-price-115" data-price-amount="875.952001" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
    <span class="price">£875.95</span>    </span>
    </span>
```

s you can see there is NO microdata here, but the schema.org/Product attribute is set in the body which DOES encompass all of these elements.

I am aware the formatting is not perfect in the main product microdata, but google structured data test comes back as OK, so am left wondering if the google bot is picking up on the duplicate class 'price' OR the fact the product attribute is effectively page wide?

Anyone seen this before? It is causing havoc with our related item product pages in that google is disallowing the feed for these items seemingly at random.

Comment: Literally started noticing this problem the other day too. From my investigations so far it looks to be a caching issue.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any logs? I have seen some sporadic faults to do with the colinmollenhour caching in ours.
We are testing upsell products to see if they have a different effect in the google feed, as the code they produce is different in that it includes the schema.org/Offers element for each of the upsell product prices as well as the main product on the page.... I am wondering whether that is the bug... perhaps all prices need a schema tag otherwise google marks as dissaproved because you maybe trying to fake the page!?

Comment: From other posts here it seems that it is very important that pages do not contain more than one schema.org/Offers tag as it confuses google... problem is i swear i have seen both a page output with the Offers tag on the main product and related and upsell products when fairly fresh, then gone back to review a day or so later to find the tag is gone?! think I'm going crazy....